# Python While Loop with Multiple Conditions not Exiting

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a code in which exits only when anyone of the 3 variables cross 7

```
while(a!=7 or b!=7 or c!=7):

   #My algorithm to increase values based on input
#end of while
```

My code never exits the while loop when anyone of of the variables cross 7.
However when I change the code to

```
while(a!-7):

    #Algorithm
#End of while
```

and on providing inputs to increase a to 7, the loop exits.

Is there some mistake in my syntax for while loop with multiple condition or is it something else?

**The algorithm that I have written in works perfectly, only the while loop cannot exit on reaching the condition for anyone of the variable**

Comment: They all need to be 7. Use `and` instead of `or`.

Comment: Your logic is wrong, it should be `and` not `or`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to exit when *any* of `a`, `b` or `c` are not equal to 7. You should use `and` and not `or`

```
while(a!=7 and b!=7 and c!=7):
```